# asnycData did not work on page reload in NuxtJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, asyncdata

I use asyncData for get dynamic post from api.

in localhost set in view source by rferesh and routing.

but in server in refresh not work asyncData() !

```
 async asyncData({ params,store , app, route, $axios }) {
    console.log("asyncData");
    try {
      const post = await $axios.get("/api/post/post?slug=lorem-ipsum-manadar-vaghei");
      return {
        post: post.data.result,
      };
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
```

Comment: What are you looking for and what is the error?

Comment: not work ! no error ! in async data get dynamic post and set to post but refresh not set post!

Comment: by refresh not console.log("asyncdata") but routing loged

Comment: Do you mean page reload or data refresh?

Comment: yes . after reload page not work asyncData

Comment: worked. but not set data

Comment: @mr.zahmatkesh hows your solution? I got this problem too

Comment: @kusiaga post answer

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue because I was defining the same property returned by `async asyncData()` also in this:

```
data() {
    return {
     service: [] // this needs to be removed and only returned by the asyncData method.
  }
}
```

All needed is something like this:

```
  async asyncData({ route, $axios }) {
    const service = await $axios.get(`https://backend/api/json/services/${route.params.nid}?_format=json`)
    return { service: service.data[0] }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved by :

```
 async asyncData(context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        try {
          const url = "/api/test";
          const postData = await context.$axios.$get(url);
          resolve({
            post: postData.result,
          });
        } catch (e) {
          reject("error");
          console.log(e);
        }
      }, 500);
    });
  },
```